# Rhapsody 8.0.5 add to model issue

Tags: rhapsody

I am trying to add a package in Rhapsody model via "Add to model" property of Rhapsody 8.0.5, but it is giving me an error that the file is a renamed version of an already existing file. Kindly let me know the reason behind it and a possible solution apart from loading the file with some different name.

[image]

Comment: Hi can anyone help me with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Each element in a Rhapsody model has a unique ID. The dialog that you encountered is shown when Rhapsody recognizes that you are trying to "add to model" an element that has the same ID as an element that already exists in the model. (There are a number of scenarios that can lead to this situation, for example, copying projects in your file system).

So, in this dialog, Rhapsody is basically offering three ways to resolve the ID conflict:

- cancel the loading of the element
- replace the existing element in the model with the one you are adding
- add the element to the model with a different name **and a different ID as well**

Comment: hi thanks for the help but  my keen interest here is how to add without using different name.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way I know is:

- edit with a text editor the sbs file to export and remove the whole line almost at the beginning of document  starting with: _id = GUIDxxxx
- then you can add the unit without any issue.
- note that there might be class names clashes if you don't properly clean the model and the importing unit.

Answer (score 1):

Rhapsody offers you everything you need in the dialog you posted here.
Rhp sees that you have already a Package with the same name and very likely the same content in your model. 
So you could simply replace it by this version or you import your package with an other name and you can compare the content of the two versions